# not work Multi AJAX code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi I have a problem when I run the code a second code will not run.
However when the second code to be executed each time the code still runs.
The first code adds value to the database and database re-runs and the second code amount removed from the table, but only the amount that was removed from the environment.

my problem is jQuery does not execute on div loaded with ajax!

How to bind click event on dynamically added element for this code?
How to solve this problem??

first code:

```
<script>
            $('#submit').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var data = $('#create').serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-Token': $('input[name="_token"]').val()
                    },
                    type: 'post',
                    url: '{!! URL::route('category') !!}',
                    data: data,
                    success: function (data) {
                        var dataDelete = 'category/' + data.id + '/delete';
                        var dataCat = data.cat;
                        var dataId = data.id;
                        $('#append').load('loadCat');
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                        alert(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).category[0]);
                    }

                });
                jQuery("#create").val('');
            });
        </script>
```

Second:

```
<script>
        $('[data-delete]').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var this_ = $(this);
            var token = $('input[name="_token"]').attr('value');
            var id = $(this).data("id");
            $.ajax(
                    {
                        url: "{{ url('/category') }}" + '/' + id + '/delete',
                        type: 'post',
                        dataType: "JSON",
                        data: {"id": id, '_token': token},
                        success: function (data) {
                            $(this_).parent().parent().remove();
                        }
                    });
            console.log("It failed");
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Is the `[data-delete]` element appended to the DOM by the first AJAX call?

Comment: Won't second code allways return it failed?

Comment: Not only is failed when the code is executed @54N1

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I did not catch you

Comment: @MeysamSaberi is the code is execute, the deleted one..??

Comment: my problem is jQuery does not execute on div loaded with ajax

Answer (score 2):

It might be because you are binding click event on Dynamically generated element.

You need to do something link

```
$("#parent_id_or_class").on('click','.dynamicAddedElement_id_class',function(){
 // Code logic

});
```

Answer (score 0):

by this code my problem is solved.

```
$('body').on('click', '[data-delete]',function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var this_ = $(this);
            var token = $('input[name="_token"]').attr('value');
            var id = $(this).data("id");
            $.ajax(
                    {
                        url: "{{ url('/category') }}" + '/' + id + '/delete',
                        type: 'post',
                        dataType: "JSON",
                        data: {"id": id, '_token': token},
                        success: function () {
                            $(this_).parent().parent().remove();
                        }
                    });
            console.log("It failed");
        });
```